# Where is the Jade's extend/block/append/prepend documentation?

Tags: pug

I'm trying to find the proper docs on Jade's `extends ...`, `block append ...`, and `block prepend ...` but I can't find any of those words in the [official doc](http://jade-lang.com/reference)..

Comment: A document issue has been opened yesterday : https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/1366

Comment: cool. I found this in the meantime. http://www.learnjade.com/tour/block-append-and-prepend/